# Amazon Transcoder Client issue with Pipelines Job on CURL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am quite new to amazon web services, and i am working on video encode and create thumbnail under amazong transcoder srevices.

```
require 'lib/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;
// Create a service locator using a configuration file
$client = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'xxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxx',
        'region' => 'ap-southeast-2',
));

$result = $client->createJob(array(
        'PipelineId' => 'xxxxx',
        'Input' => array(
          'Key' => 'video.MOV',
          'FrameRate' => 'auto',
          'Resolution' => 'auto',
          'AspectRatio' => 'auto', 
          'Interlaced' => 'auto',
          'Container' => 'auto'
        ),
        'Output' => array(
          'Key' => 'output.mp4',
          'ThumbnailPattern' => 'thumb{count}.jpg',
          'Rotate' => 'auto',
          'PresetId' => '1351620000001-000010'
        ),
));
```

somehow i am keep getting this following error: Any one can help? CURL is been enabled tho.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 6: Couldn't resolve host 'elastictranscoder.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com' [url] https://elastictranscoder.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/scavideo/server/lib/aws/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php on line 258
( ! ) Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException: [curl] 6: Couldn't resolve host 'elastictranscoder.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com' [url] https://elastictranscoder.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/scavideo/server/lib/aws/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 359
Call Stack
```

here is my CURL setting

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.41.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   No
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8zd
ZLib Version    1.2.8
```

thanks heaps

Comment: i am also getting this issue how did you resolve it?